Getting 404 error when reloading page using Firebase Hosting
I have an react + vite project hosted on Firebase Hosting
Previously after i deployed changes to hosting, i had and error in console:

Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

i resolved it by changing:
"source": "."
to:
"public": "dist"
in firebase.json.
With this change, i can see my website on hosting. But i noticed, that if i will reload page on any other page than root one, i will receive 404 page with this text:

Page Not Found
This file does not exist and there was no index.html
found in the current directory or 404.html in the root directory.
Why am I seeing this? You may have deployed the wrong directory for
your application. Check your firebase.json and make sure the public
directory is pointing to a directory that contains an index.html file.
You can also add a 404.html in the root of your site to replace this
page with a custom error page.

my current firebase.json:
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",

    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "frameworksBackend": {
      "region": "europe-west1"
    }
  },
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/robots.txt",
      "destination": "/robots.txt"
    },
    {
      "source": "**",
      "destination": "/index.html"
    }
  ]
}

What should i do to resolve it.

So i did resolve this problem just now, i again returned "source": "." and removed source of robots.txt. Firebase.json can't have 2 sources
